# Why is it helpful to use irb (as opposed to a GUI-based testing method) when coding with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, irb

I've read that the purpose of irb when programming with Ruby is to help test code in real-time.  I've learned HTML and CSS prior to this, and at that time I was able to test my code by simply opening the page in a browser and saving/refreshing the page.  Does irb perform a similar function with Ruby?  And if so, am I right to think that the benefit of testing Ruby code in irb (as opposed to the browser) is that irb makes it easier to separate errors in Ruby from errors in Javascript / HTML / etc.?  Seeing as Ruby programs will (theoretically) sooner or later be run in the browser anyway, it seems to me like a programmer would want the test conditions to be as close as possible to the real-life use case environment.

Comment: Not to mention, eliminating irb (and the command line in general) would mean one less thing for newbies like me to learn.  Principle of Least Astonishment etc.  I guess I'm just missing some of the advantages that help irb outweigh its disadvantages.  Thanks for helping a newbie everyone. :-)

Comment: Unlike HTML/CSS, Ruby is not a markup language. And, "Ruby programs will sooner or later be run in the browser" -- I have no idea what you are mentioning.

Comment: Prior to reading the answer from user limelights, I was under the impression that Ruby is only a web language, i.e. it's only executed in a web browser.  This is what I was refering to when I said 'Ruby programs will sooner or later be run in the browser.'  Thanks limelights for clearing this up, as well as for answering my overall question.

Comment: wow you're extremely confused.

Comment: @banister- yep, because I'm new to programming, just like we all were at one point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So this question relates to testing and that's a very broad topic but I'll try to answer your question from my point of view.

First and foremost we have to agree on a platform on which to stand when talking about Ruby and related web-technologies.

1 - Ruby isn't strictly a web language. This is a HUGE misconception. Ruby is not Ruby on Rails. And thusly while most applications end up in the browser nowadays, its thanks to RoR and not Ruby.

Ruby is a jack-of-all-trades kind of language, ie. it can do many things. Scripting, web, "normal applications". If you have a problem, Ruby can as a language more than likely solve it.

2 - IRB is Ruby's REPL (Read eval print loop) or, more commonly interpreter, it's not the compiler. It stands for Interactive RuBy shell.

So on to your question:

You don't test perse with IRB, you use IRB to test smaller type statements like `1 + 1` or perhaps

```
my_name = "henrik"
my_age = 28
p = Person.new(my_name, my_age)
p.my_name
>> "henrik"
```

You can think of IRB as "your small testing wizard", ie. "Does this work, let's try it in IRB!".

For real-life testing as you describe it you use `RSpec` or other types of testing frameworks and if you want to do stand alone testing you might do `ruby my_test_file.rb`. Where your `my_test_file.rb` contains all of your tests.

[RSpec](http://rspec.info/) read this, this is extremely valuable when starting with tests in Ruby.

Doing testing the way you're describing is extremely tedious but it has nothing to do with IRB .

Answer (score 0):

irb is for me for exploratory testing, trying out single lines of code. It also allows you to use Ruby's introspection to explore what's available. One thing I do a *lot* goes like this:

```
irb
1.9.3-p327 :001 > s = "This is a string"
 => "This is a string"
1.9.3-p327 :002 > s.methods.sort - Object.methods
 => [:%, :*, :+, :<<, :[], :[]=, :ascii_only?, :between?, :bytes, :bytesize, :byteslice, :capitalize, :capitalize!, :casecmp, :center, :chars, :chomp, :chomp!, :chop, :chop!, :chr, :clear, :codepoints, :concat, :count, :crypt, :delete, :delete!, :downcase, :downcase!, :dump, :each_byte, :each_char, :each_codepoint, :each_line, :empty?, :encode, :encode!, :encoding, :end_with?, :force_encoding, :getbyte, :gsub, :gsub!, :hex, :index, :insert, :intern, :length, :lines, :ljust, :lstrip, :lstrip!, :match, :next, :next!, :oct, :ord, :partition, :prepend, :replace, :reverse, :reverse!, :rindex, :rjust, :rpartition, :rstrip, :rstrip!, :scan, :setbyte, :size, :slice, :slice!, :split, :squeeze, :squeeze!, :start_with?, :strip, :strip!, :sub, :sub!, :succ, :succ!, :sum, :swapcase, :swapcase!, :to_c, :to_f, :to_i, :to_r, :to_str, :to_sym, :tr, :tr!, :tr_s, :tr_s!, :unpack, :upcase, :upcase!, :upto, :valid_encoding?]
```

Now you can get that list in lots of other ways, but to someone like me who codes in a few different languages, and knows the *sort* of thing I want to do, but not necessarily the right Ruby method, it's great. I can test out the method I think I need, and see that it does the right thing . . .

There are loads of other useful things too, such as calling a method in a library that you are learning to use, and checking what type of thing it returns.